# StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404 in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload the image on firestore. The photo is uploading successfully but I can't download the image url. I don't understand where is the problem.

My code is:

```
  ActivityResultLauncher<String> imageSelect;
        ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("photo");

        //img pick
        imageSelect = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                if (result != null){
                    imgPicker.setImageURI(result);
                    emptyImg = false;
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int post = random.nextInt(999999);
                    String postId = String.valueOf(post);
                    ref.child(postId+"-"+fmNumber).putFile(result)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                            image = uri.toString();
                                            System.out.println(image);
                                            Toast.makeText(FromActivity.this, "Image Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            uploadComplete = true;
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(FromActivity.this, "You don't select any image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgPicker.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
                    uploadComplete = false;
                }

            }
        });
```

It shows this error.

```
{  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
```

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Firebase Storage can't find a file using the Reference you used to get a download URL.  That's because you are not using the correct Reference with `getDownloadUrl`.

Here is what you're using to upload the file:

```
ref.child(postId+"-"+fmNumber).putFile(result)
```

Here is what you're using to get the download URL:

```
ref.getDownloadUrl()
```

These are not using the same Reference.  You should probably build a new reference variable and use it in both places to ensure they are always the same.

```
StorageReference fileRef = ref.child(postId+"-"+fmNumber);

// Then...

fileRef.putFile(result)...

// Then...

fileRef.getDownloadUrl()...
```